# Decimal String gets converted to number format when assigned using .Value()

Tags: vba, excel, type-conversion, copy

I have a dataset in which I need to transfer data to make it fit the format that is used for the interpretation of this data. To do that I need to combine two columns of data into a single column. To do so I paste the data of the second column below the data in the first column.

To do so I first add the required amount of empty rows at the desired place.
Then I need to duplicate the legend that accompanies this data. The legend has two columns, one with question identifiers and one with questions.

While duplicating this legend a type-conversion takes place implicitly which is  unwanted.

I use the following code to duplicate the legend:

```
Dim j as long
For j = 1 To numberrows_kennis 
   wss.cells(lastrow_kennis + j , 1) = wss.cells(row_kennis -1 + j , 1).Value
   wss.cells(lastrow_kennis + j , 2) = wss.cells(row_kennis -1 + j , 2).Value
Next j
```

In this code all variables are explicitly declared as the appropriate type (`worksheet` for wss, `Long` for the row related variables)

When I run this code most of the copying goes right, except for one value.
There is a value of `3.2` which is stored as a string, since I use a european version of excel. When I copy this over it gets converted to a decimal value instead of a string: `3,2`.

The rest of the range to be copied over are values of the `Long` type, which should not be converted to String values.

Does this type conversion originate from my use of `.Value`? And if so, how to avoid this behaviour?

Comment: No, it's Excel trying to be helpful. Either prefix the value with an apostrophe when assigning it to the cell or use a Text format for the cell (`Numberformat = "@"`)

Comment: Use [Cstr()](https://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/cstr.php)

Comment: @Sgdva, thanks for the suggestion, but that would require me to build an exception into the code, as this is only one value out of the ~ 30 values to be copied.

Comment: @Rory, that would also explicitly convert the rest of the values in my range to strings. I'll better explain in my question that this is an exceptional case in my range.

Comment: There is no other option.

Comment: Thanks @Rory, luckely the string is always found at a fixed place, so: `If j = 1 Then wss.cells(lastrow_kennis , 1).NumberFormat = "@"` did the trick.

Comment: @Rory, also if you like, write up an answer please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's Excel trying to be helpful. To avoid the automatic conversion, you must either prefix the value with an apostrophe when assigning it to the cell, or use a Text format for the cell before putting the value in it, like this:

```
wss.cells(lastrow_kennis + j , 1) = "'" & wss.cells(row_kennis -1 + j , 1).Value
```

or:

```
wss.cells(lastrow_kennis + j, 1).NumberFormat = "@"
```